# How do I show more or less of an element depending on window size?

Tags: flutter, responsive

I would like to have a banner widget, probably a VideoPlayer (from the video_player plugin) or else just an image.

Depending on the size of the screen/window I want my banner to follow like this:

https://i.imgur.com/YADZSrV.mp4

Imagine that the scaling in the video is the window size changing.

Basically:
If aspect gets wider than the original -> show less on top and bottom (kinda zooming in)
If aspect gets taller than the original -> show less on the sides (kinda cropping while centering)

I got something to work partially. It works when making the window wider, but when it gets slimmer it just starts to scale everything down, it doesn't keep the full height while showing less on the sides.

Here is my work in progress:

```
return ClipRect(
  child: OverflowBox(
    maxWidth: double.infinity,
    maxHeight: double.infinity,
    child: Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: You might want to look at the [transform widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform-class.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved very easily by using the **FittedBox** widget and the **BoxFit** enum.

```
FittedBox(
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  child: Container(
    width: 960,
    height: 360,
    child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
  ),
)
```

Using the **VideoPlayer** widget as a child of a Container where I set the size to the original size of the video.

Example using an image:

```
FittedBox(
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  child: Image(
    image: NetworkImage(
        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl-2.jpg'),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LayoutBuilder to get the size of its content and render differently accordingly:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html

In you case, it would be something like this :

```
  return ClipRect(
    child: OverflowBox(
      maxWidth: double.infinity,
      maxHeight: double.infinity,
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          if (constaints.bigger.width > constaints.bigger.height) {
            return Text('More width than height');
          }
          else {
            return Text('More height than width');
          }
        }
      )
    ),
  );
```